# What does "we sent his way" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning

The following paragraph is from "Diary of a Wimpy Kid 2" written by Jeff Kinney.

> I'm sure our Giving Tree guy will throw his sweater in the trash, along with the ten cans of yams ***we sent his way*** during the Thanksgiving Food Drive.

It seems that there are a lot of usages of "way", and I don't understand how it's used in this sentence. What does "we sent his way" mean?

I can't find any explanation of that kind of usage even after checking in a couple of online dictionaries.

Comment: What research have you done to try and answer this question? What do you think these might mean?

Comment: @WendiKidd No, I haven't done any research. I read this book and I found some of the sentences in this book are difficult to understand.So I want to figure them out.

Comment: [drive](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/drive#drive__39)

Comment: ELL is not intended to be a first-line question-and-answer service. When you don't know what a word means, check a dictionary. If you still can't figure out what a word means, then ask here, but be sure to indicate why you are still confused. It's not our job to look up words in the dictionary for you. By the way, you are right: "way" has several different meanings. "Send one's way" means to send something to someone, like when I say to my son at college, "I'll be sending some cash your way soon."

Comment: @J.R. I suspect part of the difficulty is that user48070 didn't manage to parse the sentence. There's an implicit *that* after “the ten cans of yams”: “the ten cams of yams [that] we sent his way”, i.e. “We sent ten cams of yams his way during the Thanksgiving Food Drive. I'm sure our Giving Tree guy will throw his sweater in the trash along with those cans of yams.” So it's *send something somebody's way*.

Comment: @Gilles: Good point. To be clear about this, I think that "What does _sent his way_ in this context mean?" would be an **excellent** question for this site. It's **not** something easily found in a dictionary, unlike the accompanying question about _drive_. This question doesn't need much to be reopened. The O.P. can simply consult a dictionary about the word _way_, describe why that hasn't answered his question, remove the part about _Drive_, and I'd be more than happy to reopen this question. If that happens, I hope you'll take a crack at answering it.

Comment: @J.R. I've edited the question down to “sent his way”. I can't find any explanation of that part in a couple of online dictionaries (I haven't looked closely, either it's not explained at all, or maybe you have to figure out which entry for *way* applies even though it doesn't use the verb *send*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, *way = direction*, so it means we sent ten cans of yams *in his direction, towards him*.

It's an informal idiomatic expression which can always be replaced by ***to [whoever]***, but sometimes that underlying "literal" meaning imparts a slight nuance. For example, you might be slightly more inclined to use it if you're *diverting* something that would otherwise have been sent somewhere else. Or if the recipient/location/route you're sending it to/through is somehow "non-standard" for the thing being sent.

Answer (score 2):

"[someone's] way" means their location (not direction). "Are you going out John's way?" means "Are you going to be in John's area?" "I'll send some your way" just means "I'll send some to where you work/live."